# How do I remove and then open a file for writing in python?

Tags: python

Here is some code.

```
sbfldr = input('Enter subfolder name: ')
try:
  os.remove(os.path.join(sbfldr, 'Report.html'))
except:
  print('Remove error. Please close the report file')
  exit()
try:
  fwrite = open(os.path.join(sbfldr, 'Report.html'),'a')
  exit()
except:
  print('Open error. Please close the report file')
  exit()
```

The results I expect are

1. If an old version of 'Report.html' exists, then remove it.
2. Open a new 'Report.html' for writing.

When I search for this question I get lots of answers (to other questions). This is probably because the answer is very easy, but I just do not understand how to do it.

Comment: Aren't you looking for `with open('somefile.txt', 'w+') as f:` ? Note the `w+`.

Comment: The `+` in `w+` is for updating (i.e. read and write); since the question is about writing, I don't think that's necessary.

Comment: if you use `open( ..., "w")` then it will remove old content in file.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work? See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: can just use `w` here when opening, which is defined as `open for writing, truncating the file first`, so it will empty the file and write your new data. If the file didnt exist it would create it.

Comment: Beside the point, but [a bare `except` is bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54948548/4518341). You should at least change it to `except Exception`, but preferably a specific exception like `OSError`.

Comment: You should include in your question the results you ARE getting when you run your code, that you think are incorrect.  However, @furas is correct that you can just open a file for write and it will erase the old file automatically (unless it's open by someone else.)

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to remove the file when you can just empty it. File mode `w` will ["open for writing, truncating the file first"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), and if the file doesn't exist, it will create it.

```
sbfldr = input('Enter subfolder name: ')

fname = os.path.join(sbfldr, 'Report.html')
with open(fname, 'w') as fwrite:
    pass  # Actual code here
```

BTW this uses a `with`-statement, which is the best practice for opening files. As well it ignores the bad error handling ([bare `except`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54948548/4518341)) and unnecessary `exit()` in your program.

*Thanks to [@furas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1832058/furas) for [mentioning this in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59523829/how-do-i-remove-and-then-open-a-file-for-writing-in-python#comment105218803_59523829)*

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, using [`os.path.exists`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists) to check if the file exists, and [`os.remove`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.remove) to remove it if so:

```
import os
if os.path.exists("Report.html"):
    os.remove("Report.html")

with open("Report.html", "w") as f:
    pass #do your thing
```